# How can I add Azure Synapse Analytics linked service in Data Factory using Python?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, linked-service

I'm creating a Data Factory configuration and a pipeline in Python.

I successfully added Azure Blob Storage and Azure Key Vault to the linked services, but got stuck on adding (serverless)Azure Synapse Analytics, as simply I was not able to find the relevant class within `azure.mgmt.datafactory.models`. I'm sure I'm something missing, as I could add it flawlessly through UI, so there must be a way to add it within Python?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models?view=azure-python

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out Synapse can be linked to the Data Factory through `AzureSqlDWLinkedService` class

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer the following documentation for step-by-step instructions for **Azure Synapse Analytics linked service in Data Factory using Python**

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python)

Comment: Unfortunately the quickstart is not relevant to my case. I know how to link services to the Data Factory through Python. The problem is I **cannot find the relevant class** to link Synapse, and that's what the question is about.